# laravel blade dynamic array with dynamic key

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following array which has dynamic key:

```
array:2 [▼
0 => array:4 [▼
"standard_room123_adult" => "2"
"standard_room123_child" => "1"
"standard_room123_children" => "2"
"standard_room123_room" => "1"
]
1 => array:4 [▼
"group_room_adult" => "2"
"group_room_child" => "1"
"group_room_children" => "2"
"group_room_room" => "1"
]
]
```

For example in `standard_room123_room` `standard_room123` came from a database. Now the problem is, when I want to echo it in blade with session like:

```
{{session('data')[0][0]['{$room_name}_room']}}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited you question a little. However, your question is not completely clear for me. What specific problem do you have with this code? If it throws an error, can you please add the error message? If not, please describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$room_name = "standard_room123"`

```
{{ session('data')[0][0]["{$room_name}_room"] }}
```

The only change is the quotes you've used, changed ' to "

you may need to check your array nesting, if your array above is in `session('data')`, you should only need one `[0]` e.g.

```
{{ session('data')[0]["{$room_name}_room"] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @m00am said, the question is not very clear but from the code, I can see you are trying to do variable interpolation with single quotes. This doesn't work with single quotes, you have to use double quotes when trying to interpolate a variable in a string, like this:

```
{{session('data')[0][0]["{$room_name}_room"]}}
```

You can read more about it here: https://phppot.com/php/variable-interpolation-in-php/